# why we should run dse search in a seperate DC

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

What are the main advantages or factors to look, If we run Datastax Cassandra in search/SolR mode in all existing DC's.

If my current Datastax cluster with all DCs are running Cassandra on normal load, then should I switch them to enable on search mode directly??

How much load will be impacted?? Because Currently I can't see much performance difference in running applications when I am running DC in Search/SolR mode.
started with below command:

```
./dse cassandra -p cassandra-proc.pid -s
```

Can i measure that load in some way..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many factors in play - version of DSE, what kind of Search queries executed, underlying hardware, amount of data, etc. - without this data it's hard to say.

For 4.x, the one of the reasons to have Search in separate DC is that it didn't work well with vnodes. In 5.x support of vnodes improved, so you can collocate both in same DC.  But if you have very high transactional load, and a lot of Search queries, then it still makes sense to separate functionality in different DCs to provide better availability/latency guarantees, as some of Search queries could require quite a lot of resources.

Comment: I got your reply, but If I am using DSE 5 & vnodes not enabled yet. then what would u suggest? Also Does it make sense to have less number of nodes in Search DC than normal Cassandra DC?

Comment: Yes, you may have fewer nodes in the "Search DC" if you use another replication factor, and the load isn't so high as in "Transactional DC". But you need to make sure that, for example, if one node will go down, and RF=2, then the node that is left will handle the increased load.

Comment: yes Alex that make sense to me, I will be having LOCAL_QUORUM on each SolR DC And yes Load is not that much.